# Why label text is getting changed after clicking on asp.net button?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a WebForm ASP label and button. I am setting the label's value on page load. For example, the label text on page load is `2 items selected`. This comes from the database. Then if the user changes the selection then it counts the selected values by jQuery and sets the text as `5 items selected`.

When I click on the submit button to save changes, again it resets to `2 items selected`. I didn't use an update panel. I don't know what is going on here. Can anyone please explain this scenario?

```
$("#lblCount").text($('#grdProducts').find('input#chkSelect:checked').length + ' Complementary Products added');
```

C# on page load:

```csharp
lblCount.Text = ComplementaryproductCount.ToString() + " Complementary Products added";
```

I do not understand why the label text is changed on button click. I couldn't find anything while debugging too.

Thanks

Comment: Are you committing the jquery change to the server in some way so that it will be reflected when the page is reloaded?

Comment: yeah, I am saving updated count into database. but one more thing is, I am not populating all data on page load every time. so, on button click, it won't populate data again. So, my concern is it should remain same as i set from jquery. Why its getting changed?

Comment: If the page is reloading, what you did prior with jQuery will have no effect after, so my guess would be that you are not checking the inputs before setting the label.

Comment: On load, I am showing text from database for already saved items count. using Jquery, I am setting text for new selected item's count. But on save, I am not populating data again, as new values for all controls are there except this label. @iamdlm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `lblCount.Text` in your code, that value is set into the `ViewState` of the page... that means when your page is posted back to the server (to handle an event, etc) ASP.Net knows what `lblCount.Text` was originally and can re-render the HTML with the same value.

As part of that post-back to the server, the browser will send back that `ViewState` along with any input control values (things like textboxes, dropdowns, hidden field).

What it does NOT do is post-back any changes you might have made to the elements on the page via things like jQuery (other than input controls I mentioned above).

The result is that although you've changed the element on the screen, the server knows absolutely nothing about that change, and it will re-send the original HTML for the label back to the browser.

Your only option is to do something as suggested by @John in his comment... you need to store the fact the element has changed in an input, and then use that.

For instance...

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblCount" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hdnCount" />

function updateCount(newCount) {
  $("#<%=lblCount.ClientID%>").text("Count: " + newCount.toString());
  $("#<%=hdnCount.ClientID%>").val(newCount.toString());
}
```

Then in your code-behind you can have...

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   var count = 1;
   lblCount.Text = String.Format("Count: {0}", count);
   hdnCount.Value = count.ToString();
}
else
{
   lblCount.Text = String.Format("Count: {0}", hdnCount.Value);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. It's not an easy concept to get your head around, but it's quite an important one for ASP.Net development (especially when DOM manipulation is concerned). Please remember to tick the answer you found most useful, that way the community knows your issue is solved, and you also get very useful reputation that will allow to you to do more things on the site